# Close gmail after sent an email

Tags: android, email, android-intent, send

My App send email via intent and works very fine.
The problem is, after the first email,  i can't send further email because gMail (in this case) although it seems to work perfectly, does not send anything, because, i think, it remain opened in background.
So, I have to close my app, kill all processes (and thus kill Gmail) with a task-killer and reboot.
Is there a way to close the email client  after sent the first email?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Here is the intent:

```
private void shareIntent(String string) {
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
saveDir=("/Scorepad/.temp");
        if (string=="png" ) {
        exportToBmpHandler("Shared_Image", saveDir);// here create and     save the bitmap
        sharingIntent.setType("image/png");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/Scorepad/.temp/Shared_Image.png")); 
        }
        else {
            try {
            exportPdf("Shared_Pdf", saveDir+"/"); // here create and save the pdf
            } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
            sharingIntent.setType("image/pdf");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/Scorepad/.temp/Shared_Pdf.pdf")); }
try {
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image using"), EMAIL);
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

} finally {}
}
```

And this is the Activity onResult:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if (requestCode == PICK_PROJECT_FILE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
// .................
}

if (requestCode == CREATE_CHORDS && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
// .............
}

if(requestCode==EMAIL && resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK){ 
Toast.makeText(this, "Mail sent.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
/*  if (requestCode==EMAIL && resultCode==Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)
{ Toast.makeText(this, "Mail canceled.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();} */

super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: can you show us what tried so far? Can you show us your code?

Comment: Hi B770, the purpose is to send a bitmap as attachement  and this is ok for the first email. To send other emails with bitmap i must close the app, clean with task manager and restart. Thanks for your attention

Comment: have you tried to log the different steps? Perhaps something is blocking. By logging the different steps you can see where the problem occures.

Comment: I have the same problem, 3rd party app only sends one email with attachment if target email is the same. However it sends two emails when I send to two different target email address. It sucks

Comment: failure of result delivery

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out, Gmail sort of only sends an email which has either different subject, content, attachment or cc/bcc than the last email sent within several minutes.